# When I use pd.crosstab it keeps showing AssertionError

Tags: python, pandas, knn

When I use `pd.crosstab` to build confusion matrices, it keeps showing

```
AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import random

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\liukevin\\Desktop\\winequality-red.csv',sep=';', usecols=['fixed acidity','volatile acidity','citric acid','residual sugar','chlorides','free sulfur dioxide','total sulfur dioxide','density','pH','sulphates','alcohol','quality'])

Q=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['quality'][i]<=5:
        Q.append('Low')
    else:
        Q.append('High')

del df['quality']
test_number=sorted(random.sample(xrange(len(df)), int(len(df)*0.25)))
train_number=[]
temp=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp.append(i)
train_number=list(set(temp)-set(test_number))

distance_all=[]
for i in range(len(test_number)):
    distance_sep=[]
    for j in range(len(train_number)):
        distance=pow(df['fixed acidity'][test_number[i]]-df['fixed acidity'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['volatile acidity'][test_number[i]]-df['volatile acidity'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['citric acid'][test_number[i]]-df['citric acid'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['residual sugar'][test_number[i]]-df['residual sugar'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['chlorides'][test_number[i]]-df['chlorides'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['free sulfur dioxide'][test_number[i]]-df['free sulfur dioxide'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['total sulfur dioxide'][test_number[i]]-df['total sulfur dioxide'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['density'][test_number[i]]-df['density'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['pH'][test_number[i]]-df['pH'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['sulphates'][test_number[i]]-df['sulphates'][train_number[j]],2)+\
        pow(df['alcohol'][test_number[i]]-df['alcohol'][train_number[j]],2)
        distance_sep.append(distance)
    distance_all.append(distance_sep)

for round in range(5):
    K=2*round+1

    select_neighbor_all=[]
    for i in range(len(test_number)):
        select_neighbor_sep=np.argsort(distance_all[i])[:K]
        select_neighbor_all.append(select_neighbor_sep)

    prediction=[]
    Q_test=[]
    for i in range(len(test_number)):
        Q_test.append(Q[test_number[i]])
        #original data
        Low_count=0
        for j in range(K):
            if Q[train_number[select_neighbor_all[i][j]]]=='Low':
                Low_count+=1
        if Low_count>(K/2):
            prediction.append('Low')
        else:
            prediction.append('High')

    print pd.crosstab(Q_test, prediction, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
```

But aren't the length of `Q_test` and `prediction` the same?
I guess it might be the problem that `"names" must have the same length` because I am not really sure what it means.
(In `Q_test` and `prediction` arrays, there are only binary elements `'Low'` and `'High'`.) 
`select_neighbor_all` is what I did to select K nearest neighbors of `ith` test data.

Comment: what is `pd.crosstab` what library

Comment: What do you get if you print the lengths of Q_test and prediction?

Comment: I have tried to print the length of Q_test and prediction and they are both 399 so I'm sure it's the same length.

Comment: import pandas as pd

Comment: what is in test_number?
what is Q?
Assisting you will be much easier, if you can edit your question to produce a complete question with sample data and all the details provided. = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you may not be providing all the data that pd.crosstab needs to perform the necessary calculations:

Take a look at this example. Here we provide an index AND two column categories AND rownames and colnames:

```
>>> index = np.array(["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar",
...                   "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo", "foo"], dtype=object)
>>> col_category_1 = np.array(["one", "one", "one", "two", "one", "one",
...                            "one", "two", "two", "two", "one"], dtype=object)
>>> col_category_2 = np.array(["dull", "dull", "shiny", "dull", "dull", "shiny",
...                            "shiny", "dull", "shiny", "shiny", "shiny"],
...                            dtype=object)


# Notice the index AND the columns provided as a list    
>>> pd.crosstab(index, [col_category_1, col_category_2], 
                    rownames=['a'], colnames=['b', 'c'])
... 
col_category_1   one        two
col_category_2   dull shiny dull shiny
index
bar              1     2    1     0
foo              2     2    1     2
```

For more details, see the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) for `pd.crosstab`:

> index : array-like, Series, or list of arrays/Series
>       Values to group by in the rows
>
> columns : array-like, Series, or list of arrays/Series
>       Values to group by in the columns
>
> rownames : sequence, default None
>       If passed, must match number of row arrays passed
>
> colnames : sequence, default None
>       If passed, must match number of column arrays passed

If you edit the following line, and include the correct inputs, it should solve your problem...

```
# You will need to provide an index and columns...
# Here, 'Q_test' is being interpreted as your index
# 'prediction' is being used as a column... 
pd.crosstab(Q_test, prediction, 
            rownames=['Actual'], 
            colnames=['Predicted'],
            margins=True)
```

Comment: After I remove `rownames` and `colnames` it showed another error:

    If using all scalar values, you must pass an index


----------

Comment: @k3513662  i am researching this. I appreciate that you elaborated in your question. That is a step in the right direction. I was able to find the original data for wine_quality on the web. However, when I cut and paste your code,; Q is not defined. K is not defined.  A fundamental characteristic for us to help questioners it to be able duplicate what you do and the results that you get back. What is Q, what is K? what is train_number? what is select_neighbor_all?

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions. I am so sorry that I didn't post my entire code because I thought this is my course homework and if I post my entire code it would be like asking people to do my homework, is it? This is my first question on stackoverflow so I'm not really sure whether I can post my code or not. Sorry about that and I've edited the code again. Thank you so much.

Comment: @k3513662 I have revised my answer slightly, in a direction that may provide better input...

Answer (score 1):

I just spent some time on resolving this. In my case it was that pandas crosstab does not seem to work with lists.

If you convert your lists to numpy arrays it should work fine.

So in your case it would be:

```
pd.crosstab(np.array(Q_test), np.array(prediction), rownames=['Actual'],
            colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
```

An example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> classifications = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> predictions = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']
>>> pd.crosstab(classifications, predictions, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bastian/miniconda3/envs/machine_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py", line 563, in crosstab
    rownames = _get_names(index, rownames, prefix="row")
  File "/home/bastian/miniconda3/envs/machine_learning/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py", line 703, in _get_names
    raise AssertionError("arrays and names must have the same length")
AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length
>>> pd.crosstab(np.array(classifications), np.array(predictions), rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'])
Predicted  bar  foo
Actual             
bar          1    1
foo          1    1
```

This happens because some operations like multiplication have different effects on lists than on numpy arays, I think.